# SimpleAdapter arraylist showing same data in each row

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have four bluetooth devices for testing get the bluetooth devices name and address, Called deviceA , deviceB, deviceC & deviceD
My program can get the devices one by one through mReceiver, but the SimpleAdapter array listrow have a problem. When I scan the new device, all rows will be changed as same name and address. I can't found the problem in where. Please help, Thanks.

My Problem eg:

first When scaned deviceA, Result is

deviceA AddressA

secound When scaned deviceB, Result is

deviceB AddressB

deviceB AddressB

Third When scaned deviceC, Result is
deviceC AddressC

deviceC AddressC

deviceC AddressC

Fourth When scaned deviceB again, Result is

deviceB AddressB

deviceB AddressB

deviceB AddressB

deviceB AddressB

When scaned deviceD, Result is

deviceD AddressD

deviceD AddressD

deviceD AddressD

deviceD AddressD

deviceD AddressD

this is my code:

```
private static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private static BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = null;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> list = null;
private SimpleAdapter adapter = null; 
private Map<String,Object> hashmap = new HashMap<String,Object>(); 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.getbluetooth);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
            list = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(); 
            find_bluetooth();     
}

public void find_bluetooth()
{ 
        Set<BluetoothDevice> setPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
   registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); 

       adapter = new impleAdapter(Diver_getEvents.this,list,R.layout.bluetooth_list,new String[]{"devicename","deviceaddress"},new int[]{R.id.devicename,R.id.deviceaddress});

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
        @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,long  id) 
        {
                      mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }
        }

   private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
         {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
          {
               String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
              {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
               String deviceBTName = device.getName();
    String deviceBaddress = device.getAddress();
    hashmap.put("devicename",deviceBTName);  
    hashmap.put("deviceaddress",deviceBaddress);  
    list.add(hashmap); 
               listView.setAdapter(adapter);
              }
         }
       }

}
```

Comment: You might want to attach the code for your 'impleAdapter' (i.e. the ArrayAdapter implementation).

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new HashMap each time you add it to the list

```
hashmap = new HashMap<String,Object>()
// put some values to hashmap
...
...
list.add(hashmap)
```

Comment: My New code : 
        String deviceBTName = device.getName();
                    String deviceBaddress = device.getAddress();
                    hashmap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    hashmap.put("devicename",deviceBTName);  
                    hashmap.put("deviceaddress",deviceBaddress);  
                    list.add(hashmap); 
                   adapter = new  SimpleAdapter(getEvents.this,list,R.layout.bluetooth_list,new String[]{"devicename","deviceaddress"},new int[]{R.id.devicename,R.id.deviceaddress});
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Thank you very much for all responder, I add the code teach by pskink was done.